# Count elements satisfying an extra condition on another column when group-bying in pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

The following pyspark command

```
df = dataFrame.groupBy("URL_short").count().select("URL_short", col("count").alias("NumOfReqs"))
```

created the following result.

```
|URL_short |NumOfReqs|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+
|http1     | 500    |
|http4     | 500    |
|http2     | 500    |
|http3     | 500    |
```

In the original DataFrame `dataFrame` I have a column named `success` whose type is text. The value can be `"true"` or `"false"`.

In the result I would like to have an additional column named for example `NumOfSuccess` which counts the elements having entry `"true"` in the original column `success` per category `URL_short`.

How can I modify

```
df = dataFrame.groupBy("URL_short").count().select("URL_short", col("count").alias("NumOfReqs"))
```

to output also the column satisfying the condition `success`=="true`per`URL_short` category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to add another aggregation expression (also turn the `count` into an agg expression):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

dataFrame.groupBy("URL_short").agg(
  f.count('*').alias('NumOfReqs'), 
  f.sum(f.when(f.col('success'), 1).otherwise(0)).alias('CountOfSuccess')
).show()
```

Note this assumes your `success` column is boolean type, if it's string, change the expression to `f.sum(f.when(f.col('success') == 'true', 1).otherwise(0)).alias('CountOfSuccess')`